# Computer and Internet Extremely Slow and Fan Constantly Running Audibly: 2016 15" Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, hardware

My computer is a 2016 Macbook Pro. The battery service warning came on, and I did my research and determined the battery was at the end of its life. At the same time the fan was always running audibly, which I read could happen with a failing battery.

I had the battery replaced at a local shop (not apple store), and expected it to be better. Glad I did, however now the **computer and internet are running extremely slow** now and the **fan is still constantly running audibly loud**. The computer does not feel overly hot.

I tried an SMC reset but not sure if it took because I notice no difference. I have updated to the latest OS, 12.5 because someone said there *might* be a software fix for a failing processor thermistor, (not sure what that means).

This computer is my livelihood. Looking for tips on next steps I can try without dropping it off at the apple store, which is far from here, and leaving it for an undisclosed amount of time.

What steps are next to fix this?

Comment: Did you checked in monitor if some process was taking high cpu usage ?

Answer (score 1):

You have done all the good steps, and sadly you will need to get it back to the shop that swapped the battery to repeat that service or further diagnose.

For this I would not take it to a store. Instead order a box for, Apple online so you can time when you drop it off and have it shipped to all the parts at the depot.

Retail store will likely slow down this specific repair three days in my experience. The only reason to take it to the retail store is if you think they can help with updates or settings. That will not be likely as you already found all the relevant steps (smc) and made the correct observations on the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @bmike. I ended up getting a new MBP and will revisit this once the sticker shock wears off. Appreciate it!

Comment: Congratulations! Hopefully you can have some light duty backup once you’re sure the new horse has all the weight you need being carried. @ispaany